# How to back up MySQL databases to SQL files?

Tags: php, mysql, database, backup

I'm having significant server issues at the moment, and am worried the server will go at any moment. I need to backup my SQL databases immediately.

Could I please get a command just to dump all my databases (different domains) into their own sql backup files?

I'd like to work with this cron syntax, since it already works fine for backing up individual SQL files.

```
mysqldump -uadmin2 -p$(cat /etc/psa/psa.my/.psa.myshadow) MyActualDB > /var/www2/backup/mybackup1.sql
```

The above syntax is just for one SQL file. But I need to add:

```
all-databases
```

syntax in there somewhere. Also, for each backup, to backup to their own SQL file (preferably using their already established database name).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) utility with `--all-databases` switch to dump entire databases like below

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > TotalBackup.sql
```

But above command will dump everything in a single file. Found [This blog](http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/04/backup-mysql-dump-all-your-mysql-databases-in-separate-files/) which has a nice solution to it. A script to do the job of pulling the backup in different files. Take a look.

Comment: thanks dude, I tried to vote up your response.  But it says I need 15 rep points.  I think i'm going to try that script.  Could I get the version for what I need ?     Since my password is shadow'd there -

Comment: shadowed as mysqldump -uadmin2 -p$(cat /etc/psa/psa.my/.psa.myshadow)    Not sure how to correctly add that to script.  I thank u for this.